# A probability of greater than 1?

Tags: probability

This question is a super-simplified version of and inspired by another question posted about an hour ago.

[Question regarding monkeys and probabilities.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850520/question-regarding-monkeys-and-probabilities)

---

The probability of getting a particular number (say "$4$") when rolling a fair die is $1/6$?

Does that mean the probability of getting at least one "$4$" on three attempts would be $3 \times 1/6 = 1/2$?

If so, is the probability of getting at least one "$4$" on twelve attempts $2$?

How can we explain this? I have been thinking and I don't have an answer yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*So the probability of getting at least one 4 on three attempts would be...*"  No, this is wrong.  That happens to be the correct calculation to a completely different problem... the question of "what is the expected number of 4's found after three attempts?"

Comment: To correctly calculate the probability of at least one "4"... consider instead the opposite problem... finding the probability that *no* "4"s occur, which will be $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$.  Your probability will be one minus that.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree. That's what I was thinking. But how do we explain what's going on with the probability calculation? I mean what's wrong about it?

Comment: What's wrong with it?  Letting $A$ be the event that the first roll was a 4, and $B$ the event the second roll is a 4... the probability that at least one of the first two rolls is a four is indeed equal to $\Pr(A\cup B)$ and while it is true that in *some* circumstances you have $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$, that is true only when there is not the possibility that both occur, that there is no overlap... but here you *can* have both the first and second roll be a 4.  Instead, what is generally true is $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

Comment: "*What's wrong about it?*"  You don't simply add probabilities together and expect to get another probability.  Most events will not be mutually exclusive.  Also, you don't simply multiply two probabilities together and expect to get another probability.  Most events will not be independent.  While it is true that $\Pr(A\sqcup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ when $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, it is in general not the case... and while true $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times\Pr(B)$ when $A,B$ are independent, it is in general not the case...

Comment: @JMoravitz reminds me of https://www.reddit.com/r/badmathematics/comments/4v6yy0/trump_assuming_that_no_sets_of_followers_intersect/

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thank you for the explanation you have presented. I am not sure I still understand. I mean I am sure there is an error. But there's something I am finding difficult to wrap my head around. Let me ponder over your comments and hopefully it'll bring some clarity.

Comment: @Haris The error is that „$\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)$“ is wrong in general, but in your line of reasoning you assume it is true.

Comment: With regards to the linked question... to reiterate what was said there already... in certain contexts it is permissible to *estimate* certain results by applying $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ when it is known and well understood that $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is *substantially smaller* than the other appearing numbers in the calculation.  In doing so you can quickly and easily arrive at a result that is at least *near* the correct final answer, in several real world examples getting within $.0000001$ of the true value, but again this is only valid when it is well known that it not affect final result.

Comment: Similarly, we will often simplify things and *estimate* results of the intersection of two events *as though* they are independent even when they are not because we know ahead of time that they are so very close to independent that it won't affect things.  Estimations are of course *just estimations* and taking things to the extreme like in the linked post will of course give inconsistent results.

Comment: @JMoravitz you second to last comment (along with Maximillian's and the answer posted below) kind of jolted me out of my stupidity. Thank you so much for persisting and putting in the effort. I know typing out the comments is not easy, or fun.

Comment: Although it might not be clear *what* is wrong, it should be obvious *something* is wrong.  If you roll a die $12$ times it is obviously *possible* that you won't get any $4$s (what if you rolled all sixes, or 3 sixes, 3 twos, 2 ones, 2fives and 2 threes).  "So the probability of getting at least one "4" on three attempts would be 3×1/6=1/2" Are you sure.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch thank you. Your comment was one factor that helped me recover from this embarrassing lapse of sensibility.

Comment: @fleablood Yup, there was never a doubt that something was wrong. And yes, now I realize my statement about 1/2 was wrong.

Comment: @Haris.  When I was in college there was a fast food sweepstake were they gave prizes and proabilities if you bought 1 to 6 tickets.  So the probability of willing the car with 1 ticket would be 1 in 12 million say and then they said with 2 tickets 1 in 6 million up to with 6 tickets 1 in 2 million.  But then they did it with meals, burgers and drinks.  A burger was 1 in six so if you bought six tickets they said it was 1 in 1. But drinks were 1 in 4 so if you bought 5 or 6 tickets they said the probability was "more than 1 in 1".  I was amused.

Comment: @fleablood lol, this was funny! it made me forget (momentarily) how I have embarrassed myself with this post. Thanks!

Comment: @Haris Don‘t worry, there is [no shame in asking „dumb questions“](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-and-answer-them/), I‘m glad that I was of help.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a probability more than one.     Probabilities only add when two events are mutually exclusive.  $P(A \lor B) = P(A) + P(B)$ only if $P(A \land B) = 0$.

To work out your problem, convert it to its negation:  $P(\text{at least one 4 on 12 attempts}) = 1 - P(\text{no 4s on 12 attempts}) = 1 - \frac{5}{6}^{12}$

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret the question as asking how someone could get "full credit" for the probability calculation described in
[Question regarding monkeys and probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4850520/139123)
but we can get an absurd conclusion (probability greater than $1$) by changing the numbers in the question.

Consider a coin that almost never lands heads up (probability $p$ where $p$ is a very small positive number) and an experiment where we toss this coin $n$ times.
The number of heads has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.
The probability of no heads in this distribution is $(1 - p)^n$
and the probability of at least one head is $1 - (1 - p)^n.$

By the binomial theorem,
$$ (1 - p)^n = 1 - \binom n1 p + \binom n2 p^2 - \binom n3 p^3 +- \cdots .$$

So
\begin{align}
 1 - (1 - p)^n &= \binom n1 p - \binom n2 p^2 + \binom n3 p^3 -+ \cdots \\
&= np - \frac{n(n-1)}2 p^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{2\cdot3} p^3 -+ \cdots.
\end{align}

Now suppose $np = 10^{-100}.$ Then
$\frac{n(n-1)}2 p^2 < \frac{n^2}2 p^2 < 0.5 \times 10^{-200}.$
The next term is even smaller.
It can be shown that $np$ is an excellent approximation of the probability
$1 - (1 - p)^n.$ It can also be shown that $np$ is an upper bound of $1 - (1 - p)^n.$

The approximation only gets better as $np$ gets smaller.
[Question regarding monkeys and probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4850520/139123)
actually applies this approximation twice, once for a single monkey and once for all $10^{10}$ monkeys, but in both cases $p$ is so tiny that $np$ is still much less than
$10^{-100}$ and the approximation is really very good.

For a course in physics, which was the context of [Question regarding monkeys and probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4850520/139123),
such an approximation is more than good enough and it is not surprising to see it awarded full credit.

When $np = \frac12,$ as in the case of rolling at least one $4$ in three rolls,
the approximation really is not very good.
When $np = 2,$ as in the case where you roll $12$ times,
the approximation is horrible.
In the case where $n = 12$ and $p = \frac16,$ the first term of the expansion of
$1 - (1 - p)^n$ is

$$ np = 2 $$

(of course) but the second term is

$$ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} p^2 = \frac{11}6, $$

which is almost as large as the first term.
So it makes no sense at all to use only the first term as an approximation in that case, unlike in the case of the monkeys and typewriters.

Comment: Thank you, David!